# How to split WriteLine over multiple lines?

Tags: c#

This is an example of the syntax I tried and don't want to use `\n`.

```
Console.WriteLine("x"
                  "x"
                  "x"
                  "x"
                  "x");
```

One call should yield:

```
x  
x  
x  
x  
x
```

Comment: That seems like a very strange statement. If you don't want to use `\n`, then everything will go on one line.

Comment: Is the purpose to write out many arguments with a line per argument, or are you trying to write out a single multiline string?  The latter is answered correctly below with the use of @""

Comment: I tried using @ and it worked - so the latter. What do you mean "many arguments with a line per argument?" How would that look?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One call shouldn't yield that, because you've got two string literals. In fact, that won't even compile...

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine("x\nx");
```

Or at worse:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"x
x");
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use `\n`?

Answer (score 7):

You could make it easy and use @ quoted string literals like:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"X
X
X
X
X
X");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a collection of items and want to write them all on separate lines, this is always an option:

```
var myItems = new[] { "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" };
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myItems));
// or without the collection
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"x
x
x
something
    notice this respects identation");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy as WriteLine only accepts one input parm, or a parm with formatting options, so either

```
Console.WriteLine("x\nx"); 

or

Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}","x","x","x");
```

`\n` is a 'linefeed' escaped character

(second example formats for 3 x's)

You might consider multiple WriteLines, one for each 'x'?

Answer (score 0):

One other option is something like this. (Although I think the correct answer is to use `\n`.)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteMulti("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void WriteMulti(params string[] args)
{
    foreach (string arg in args)
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you are looking for someway to write out many arguments on to a different line per argument.  A couple of options are below:

```
/// <example>
    /// Console.WriteLine(new LinesItem("X", "X"));
    /// </example>
    public class LinesItem
    {
        private readonly string _lineSeparator;
        private readonly object[] _items;

        public LinesItem(params object[] items) : this("\r\n", items)
        {
            _items = items;
        }

        public LinesItem(string lineSeparator, params object[] items)
        {
            _lineSeparator = lineSeparator;
            _items = items;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Join(_lineSeparator, _items.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
        }
    }

    //OR

    /// <summary>
    /// Because System.Console is a static class you cannot use Extension methods which would
    /// have been nice.  Instead you can simply make another static class to do extra things.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// ExtendedConsole.WriteLines("X", "X");
    /// </example>
    public static class ExtendedConsole
    {
        public static void WriteLines(params object[] items)
        {
            foreach(var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling WriteLine, you simply call Write:

```
Console.Write("x");
Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
Console.Write("x");
```

Comment: The desire was for a single method invocation.